# is return "nothing" permissible in a void function?

Tags: c++

I apologize but I am still learning. And do not touch my reputation, please:) This compiles, I just want to know if there is a better solution. I do not find it very elegant.
If (Price==0) I want to exit from the function without doing anything.

```
void Esempio(int Price)
{   
    if (Price==0)
       return;
    MyArray[0]=Price;
}
```

is this a correct way to exit a void function ? I am referring to return. It just came to my mind that I have never seen "return nothing". Anything more "elegant" ?

Thanks.

Comment: What's so inelegant other than the fact that you could just invert the if?

Comment: In terms of elegance: the use of `return;` to exit a void function is perfectly legitimate and often very useful. It is not just "some hack" to leave a void function early.

Answer (score 4):

> is this a correct way to exit a void function ?

Yes, it is.

> Anything more "elegant"

```
void Esempio(int Price)
{   
    if(Price != 0)
        MyArray[0] = Price;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, in that context anyway ( in my real code ) it was impossible to do what you suggest which is, of course, the best solution

Answer (score 1):

Yes, It works 100%,
In a void function, return means that just finish this function and return nothing!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is legal.

In fact, it you `return` other than nothing in a void function, like the following,  will cause a compile error `return-statement with a value, in function returning 'void'`

```
//illegal code
void func(void)
{
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `void` as argument is not necessary in C++(unlike C)

Answer (score 0):

I find this as an `elegant` way

```
void Esempio(int Price)
{   
   if(Price)
      MyArray[0] = Price;
 }
```

`if(Price)` means `if(Price != 0)`

In `void` function you don't need to have `return` statement at the end of the function.

You may also rethink your implementation. Do you really want to call this function, when price is `0`?

Maybe this attitude

```
void Esempio(int Price)
{   
   MyArray[0] = Price;
 }

if(Price) Esempio(Price);
```

will make your procedures simplier.

Comment: Moving the check outside the function may cause code duplication. E.g. if it's called from 3 places, you've have to check 3 times outside, versus just once inside.